# The use of objectAtIndex when adding a PFRelation in Swift using Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I'm adding a friendship relation for current user to the row which resembles another user in user table using  table view controller.
I cannot find a way of setting the selected row as a variable, in this instance the object would be called user. The way I currently have throws up an error on the objectAtIndex part.

```
var relation : PFRelation = PFUser.currentUser().relationForKey("friendship")
        let user:PFObject = self.userArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
        relation.addObject(user)
        PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeed:Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                NSLog("Unable to save")
            }
        }
```

I've looked at numerous tutorials and they seem to do it the same way. 
Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will be done with different APIs.

To retrieve the local contacts on the phone, you will need to use Address Book Framework on iOS. You can look this [Quick Start Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html).

For Facebook contact, you will have to have the user log in first. You will need to integrate [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2). During the login, you ask user to grant you permission to read some attributes. Once you get the permission, you can call Facebook API to get the data with access token Facebook issued to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll have a look at your links.